# What does "fix the flat on your car" mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

I listened Hannah Montana's song "Rock Star". Then I watched the lyrics of the song:

> I'm unusual
>       Not so typical
>       Way too smart to be waiting around
>       Tai chi practicing
>       Snowboard champion
>       **I could fix the flat on your car** //unclear
>       I might even be a rock star

Misunderstand the phrase "***fix the flat on your car***".
What does it mean? What flat does a car have? Could this mean a vehicle interior?

Answer (score 9):

**the flat** simply means [**a flat tire**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_tire). When you get a flat tire (or just a flat) on your car, there's no air in it and you can't drive (maybe you could but it would be difficult for the car to move and most likely illegal among other things). I guess, the idea here is that a deflated automobile tire actually looks flat in the area where it touches the ground, but when there's air inside, it looks round.

Example:

> — Why are you so late today?
>   — Oh, I'm sorry, I got **a flat tire** on my car on the way to work. Took me almost an entire hour to fix it. That's why I'm late.

Comment: _maybe you could but it would be difficult for the car to move_ I've no idea of the illegalities, but from a practicalities perspective, if you drive on a flat you are a) shredding the tire, there's no chance now of "fixing" the original puncture (cheap), but you have to replace the entire tire (expensive) and b) The further and faster you go you're actually going to deform the rim or the wheel it's self, and they are very expensive to replace, and rim repairs are often of questionable merit.

Comment: That's a very good point.

Comment: I was once told by my American host as we drove 'this is a bad area, if we get a flat here, we don't get out and fix it, we drive another mile on the rims!'